# How can i group data from mysql database into an html table using php

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I have two table s that i am joining together as follows

```
    <?php 
    $userqry="
    SELECT * 
      FROM permission_category c
      JOIN permission_group g
        ON c.perm_group_id = g.id 
    ";
    $stmt = $conn2->prepare($userqry);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row= $stmt->fetch()){
     } ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['perm_group_name'];?>
   </td>
   <td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Results are as follows
[image]

But The results am looking for should display as follows

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: This is a classic _control break_ implementation. Your data needs to be properly sorted to begin with. And then, in your loop over the data, you check if value (of whatever you call that first column) for the current row, it still the same, as it was for the last one. Depending on that, you decide which output needs to be created for the current row.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't see how the desired result set relates to the other one

Comment: You could use Group By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code "remembers" the previous name in your loop. If the name isn't changed it won't be displayed:

```
<?php 
$userqry = "SELECT * FROM `permission_category` 
            INNER JOIN `permission_group` ON 
            `permission_category`.`perm_group_id`=`permission_group`.`id`";
$stmt = $conn2->prepare($userqry);
$stmt->execute();

$current_name="";
while ($row= $stmt->fetch()) {
  if ($row['name'] != $current_name) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $current_name = $name;
  } else {
    $name = "";
  }
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['perm_group_name'];?>
  </td>
  <td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: You should add `ORDER BY` in your query in order to sort your result in a proper way (maybe it's already sorted)

Comment: You can ORDER BY in the query or sort the resulting array. Unless LIMITing the result, it makes no difference.